# Too many Conditional Statements

Tags: python

lets say there are 5 checkboxes and there are 5 values.

```
checkbox1 (bool)
checkbox2 (bool)
checkbox3 (bool)
checkbox4 (bool)
checkbox5 (bool)

checkbox1_value (int)
checkbox2_value (int)
checkbox3_value (int)
checkbox4_value (int)
checkbox5_value (int)
```

i want to implement logic based on which checkboxes bool is true.
if one checkbox is false and others are true.

then in the logic only 4 values should be involved of the appropriate true checkboxes.

if i do all of this on an if statement there are 120 combinations and i think there is a better option out here,

maybe someway to use overloading.

Comment: You should put a code here, and clarify what your problem is exactly.

Comment: "if i do all of this on an if statement there are 120 combinations"  - you get 5 "combinations" if you use an if and store them in some lists/tuples